# quiero crear un proyecto con react y me salta ese error

Tags: reactjs, terminal

Error en la terminal cmd.exe :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el error _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Intente seguir los comandos de la siguiente forma:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app goten-store
```